# Magento 2 Add custom discount to payment page

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-options, checkout-page

I want to add custom discount to only payment page, i am able to add discount on `checkout/cart` page using `checkout_cart_index.xml` but i need to show it only on `checkout_index_index`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="custom_discount" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Company_Test/js/view/checkout/summary/partialpayment</item>
                                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="custom_discount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test</item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Comment: What type of discount?

Comment: custom discount

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by adding same component in `checkout_index_index.xml` and in your `Company_Test/js/view/checkout/summary/partialpayment` js file

```
 return Component.extend({
    defaults:{
    visible:ko.observable(false), //by default its hidden
    },

    initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            if(your_custom_logic_to_display_component)
            {
               this.visible(true);
            }

        },

});
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: Not sure how to use it